# map json to property on knockout view model

Tags: knockout.js

This works fine:

```
var vm = {};
$.getJSON('file.json', function (data) {
    vm.objects = data;
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var vm = {
    objects: $.getJSON('file.json', function (data) {});
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Why not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $.getJSON doesn't return anything (or, at least, it doesn't return your data). It's asynchronous, so the only way to access the data is in the callback function.